# Rspec Undefined method 'should receive'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, mongoid

I'm trying to use rspec with mongoid but I'm running across this error:

```
undefined method `should_receive' for ShortenedUrl:Class
```

Here's my spec_helper.rb file:

```
# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'

# Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc,
# in spec/support/ and its subdirectories.
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

RSpec.configure do |config|
  # == Mock Framework
  #
  # If you prefer to use mocha, flexmock or RR, uncomment the appropriate line:
  #
  # config.mock_with :mocha
  # config.mock_with :flexmock
  # config.mock_with :rr
  config.mock_with :rspec

  # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
  # config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
  # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
  # instead of true.
  # config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

  config.before(:each) do
    Mongoid.master.collections.each(&:drop)
  end
end
```

And here's my test file:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe UrlsController do

  describe "POST make_short" do

    context "when posting a valid url" do
      # url = mock('ShortenedUrl')
      url = Struct.new('ShortenedUrl')
      ShortenedUrl.should_receive(:new).with(:url => 'http://example.com').and_return(url)
      url.should_receive(:save!)

      post :make_short, :url => 'http://example.com'
    end

  end

end
```

Finally, here's the Gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.0.3'
gem "mongoid", ">= 2.0.0.beta.19"
gem "rspec-rails", ">= 2.0.1", :group => [:development, :test]
gem "cucumber-rails", :group => :test
gem "capybara", :group => :test
```

From what I understand, I should get this error if I wasn't using the rspec mock, but in my case I'm using it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your test needs to be inside an `example` or `it` block (they're the same method):

```
it "when posting a valid url" do
  # url = mock('ShortenedUrl')
  url = Struct.new('ShortenedUrl')
  ShortenedUrl.should_receive(:new).with(:url => 'http://example.com').and_return(url)
  url.should_receive(:save!)

  post :make_short, :url => 'http://example.com'
end
```

A `context` block is used for grouping similar examples.

Comment: I can't believe I did that. Thanks!

Comment: Strange...I'm encoutering the same problem.  I have it in an `it` block.  But I keep getting `undefined method `should_receive' for Mailer:Class`.  This is rspec-rails 2.10.1

Comment: @BrianArmstrong Create a gist of yuor test somewhere.